# Is it possible to decrypt openssl -aes-256-cbc encrypted data using javascript?

Tags: javascript, encryption, openssl, aes, cryptojs

I am trying to decrypt the openssl -aes-256-cbc encrypted mp4 file. But after decrypting using CryptoJS i am not getting valid data. Is it possible to decrypt openssl -aes-256-cbc encrypted data using javascript?

```
var eKey = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key);
var eIv =  CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv);
var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
    CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
        ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(encrypted)
    }),
    eKey,
    {
        iv: eIv, 
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 
    }
);
```

OR

```
var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, eKey, {
    iv: eIv, 
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 
});
```

Comment: Decrypt on the server and send the mp4?  There is no effective security here if thats your intention.

Comment: If you're using only symmetric encryption you need the exact same key at the server and the client. If you send the encryption key from the server to the client or the other way around you need to encrypt your symmetric encryption key. The easiest way to do this would be to use TLS. If you use TLS, then the data as well as key are encrypted, so you don't need to encrypt it yourself. This doesn't provide any security, just a little bit of obfuscation. You should read: https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/

Comment: I am getting -aes-256-cbc encrypted file from the server and i need to decrypt using cryptojs library. The key and iv are proper. But decryption is not working.

Comment: I have the same problem exactly

Comment: Any solution for this? I have the same problem.